# How to display different content according to click of item of toolbar in iOS?

Tags: ios, uikit

Like this:

Click item1 shows a content
[image: item1]

Click item2 show2 another content
[image: item2]

However, with the upper content  not change.

Comment: `UITabBarController` ?

Comment: But upper side content view does not change, Is it suitable to use TabBar?

Comment: I added answer to elaborate on use of `UITabBarController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to create custom component you might be able to use `UITabBarController` (never tried this, but it could work):

Main idea is that ViewController does not have to control entire screen.

```
+-----+
|     |
|     |
+-----+
|  A  | 
+-----+
```

You would add `UITabBarController` as child controller to VC controlling the screen, and make it control only bottom area (A).